# 2 identical strings "not equal" [Python]

Tags: python

Found a similar question via search but I'm a new (terrible) programmer and couldn't understand the answer.

I have a .txt file with multiple strings, seperated by a '-'. I used a split to seperate some of the strings into variables, and 2 of them are equal, but in an if statement they come out as not equal.

```
f_nmr, f_Question, f_1, f_2, f_3, f_answer = file.readline().split('-')
print(f_2)
print(f_answer)
if f_2 == f_answer:
    print("Yes")
elif f_2 != f_answer:
    print("No")
```

This produces the following:

Sweden

Sweden

No

There is a space infront and after both "Sweden" strings, and they're both written with an uppercase 'S', yet are not equal? Where have I messed up?

Comment: What does the input file look like?

Comment: Try to trim both strings and then test the result with f_2.strip() and f_answer.strip().

Comment: What do `print(len(f_2))` and `print(len(f_answer))` show?

Comment: Try `print(repr(f_2))` and `print(repr(f_answer))`; I guarantee you'll see a difference.

Comment: @ShadowRanger not necessarily.  `repr('Ѕweden')` and `repr('Sweden')` looks exact the same with the glyphs in my terminal, but those strings aren't equal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last element includes a newline.  Let's take this input file as an example:

```
$ cat file.txt
Sweden-Sweden
```

Now, let's read it in:

```
>>> a, b = open('file.txt').readline().split('-')
>>> a,b
('Sweden', 'Sweden\n')
>>> a == b
False
```

The solution is to strip the newline:

```
>>> a, b = open('file.txt').readline().rstrip('\n').split('-')
>>> a == b
True
```